# Repead a PathTransition multiple times

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a program that moves multiple circles in a random way on my borderpane. I have created a method where my circles follow a random Line path on my pane. I do this via a PathTransition. They do follow the line and so move. But when they reach the end of their transition, they stop... I want them to move to another random position so they move randomly around the pane.

Here I create and add the circles with a random color, on a random position on my borderpane:

```
//Creating an array of circles and fill them
    Random random = new Random();
    Circle circles[] = new Circle[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        circles[i] = new Circle();
        circles[i].setRadius(30);
    }

    //Adding circles to pane on random position and give them random collers
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Random randon = new Random();
        int randX = randon.nextInt((int) borderPane.getWidth() - 30);
        int randY = randon.nextInt((int) borderPane.getHeight() - 30);

        int rColor = 20 + randon.nextInt(235);
        int gColor = 20 + randon.nextInt(235);
        int bColor = 20 + randon.nextInt(235);

        borderPane.getChildren().add(circles[i]);
        circles[i].setCenterX(randX);
        circles[i].setCenterY(randY);
        circles[i].setFill(Color.rgb(rColor, gColor, bColor));
    }
```

Here's the method that makes them move:

```
public void MoveCircles(BorderPane borderPane,Circle circles[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int endPosX = random.nextInt((int) borderPane.getWidth() - 30);
        int endPosY = random.nextInt((int) borderPane.getHeight() - 30);

        Line line2 = new Line(circles[i].getCenterX(), circles[i].getCenterY(), endPosX, endPosY);
        PathTransition pathTransition2 = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition2.setNode(circles[i]);
        pathTransition2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        pathTransition2.setPath(line2);
        pathTransition2.play();
    }
}
```

Here i call the method:

```
MoveCircles(borderPane,circles);
```

I've tried to repeat the method in a loop but that does not work. They just move once and stop. How can i make the method repeat over and over again so the circles keep moving. Ty in advance :)

Comment: I am not sure if `BorderPane` is the correct node here. Add a Pane to the `BorderPane.setCenter(yourPane);` and add the `Circles` to your `Pane`. Not 100% sure if this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to an SequentialTransition you can use the setOnFinished-method of the PathTransition-class. This method is called when the animation has finished. Here you can set a new path and start the animation again.

Using the setOnFinished-method the MoveCircles-method becomes:

```
public void MoveCircles(BorderPane borderPane,Circle circles[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        PathTransition pathTransition2 = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition2.setNode(circles[i]);
        pathTransition2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        pathTransition2.setPath(createPath(borderPane, pathTransition2));       
        pathTransition2.play();
        pathTransition2.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);               
        pathTransition2.setOnFinished(e -> {                        
            pathTransition2.setPath(createPath(borderPane, pathTransition2));   
            pathTransition2.play();                         
        });                                     
    }
}
```

Because the creation of the path is used twice it makes sense to move the functionality in a separate method, e.g.

```
private Line createPath(BorderPane borderPane, PathTransition pathTransition) {
    Circle circle = (Circle)pathTransition.getNode();
    Line line = (Line)pathTransition.getPath();
    Random random = new Random();
    int endPosX = random.nextInt((int) borderPane.getWidth() - 30);
    int endPosY = random.nextInt((int) borderPane.getHeight() - 30);
    return new Line(line == null ? circle.getCenterX() : line.getEndX(), line == null ? circle.getCenterY() : line.getEndY(), endPosX, endPosY); // without discontinuities
    // return new Line(circle.getCenterX(), circle.getCenterY(), endPosX, endPosY); // with discontinuities
}
```

Since the second parameter of the createPath-method is the pathTransition itself it is easy to use the end point of the previous path as the start point of 
the next path which avoids discontinuities in the consecutive motion sequences. But this is of course optional.

Answer (score 0):

When you call an animation’s `play()` method, the animation starts playing in the background.  So if you create and start several animations affecting the same Node, they all start at roughly the same time, and interfere with each other.

What you want is for multiple animations to play in sequence, one after another.  You can do this with a [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html):

```
public void moveCircles(BorderPane borderPane, Circle circles[]) {

    // Better to create one Random and keep using it to generate random values.
    Random random = new Random();

    int repeatCount = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {

        SequentialTransition sequence = new SequentialTransition();

        for (int r = 0; r < repeatCount; r++) {
            int endPosX = random.nextInt((int) borderPane.getWidth() - 30);
            int endPosY = random.nextInt((int) borderPane.getHeight() - 30);

            Line line2 = new Line(circles[i].getCenterX(), circles[i].getCenterY(), endPosX, endPosY);
            PathTransition pathTransition2 = new PathTransition();
            pathTransition2.setNode(circles[i]);
            pathTransition2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
            pathTransition2.setPath(line2);
            sequence.getChildren().add(pathTransition2);
        }

        sequence.play();
    }
}
```